# Which CSS properties are supported by which browsers?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Is there a one-page reference wherein it's listed which browsers support which CSS properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(Cascading_Style_Sheets)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29)

Here you go!
This page compares rendering engines and their support of CSS. 
At the top of the page, it says which rendering engine is used by which browser.

Comment: Try making the url
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29

(with %28 and %29 in place of ( and ) )

Answer (score 6):

Quirksmode.org has really great tables listing [everything that works in CSS/HTML/JavaScript in different browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html).